# In App Purchase: Product Information not showing up on Purchase View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase

I am setting up an InApp Purchase in an app.

I have one View Controller (**Main View Controller**) that has a button named "Buy Access".  When I tap on that button, it is pushing me to the next View Controller (**Purchase View Controller**) exactly as it should.

The problem is, the `PurchaseViewController` is not showing any information for the InApp Purchase.  I have set up an `UILabel` outlet for the Product Title, and a `UITextView` for the Product Description, but nothing is refreshing or filling in that text.

The Product ID is in the `MainViewController`.

Any ideas on what is getting stuck?

PurchaseViewController.h

```
@interface PurchaseViewController : UIViewController
<SKPaymentTransactionObserver, SKProductsRequestDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) SKProduct *product;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *productID;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *productTitle;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *buyButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *productDescription;
- (IBAction)buyProduct:(id)sender;
- (void)getProductInfo:(UIViewController *)viewController;

@property (nonatomic) int buttonNumber;

@end
```

PurchaseViewController.m

```
#pragma mark - SKProductsRequestDelegate
- (void) productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {
    NSArray *products = response.products;
    if (products.count !=0) {
        _product = products[0];
        //_buyButton.enabled = YES;
        _productTitle.text = _product.localizedTitle;
        _productDescription.text = _product.localizedDescription;
    }
    else {
        _productTitle.text = @"Product not found";
    }

    products = response.invalidProductIdentifiers;

    for (SKProduct *product in products) {
        NSLog(@"Product not found: %@", product);
    }

}



- (IBAction)buyProduct:(id)sender {
    SKPayment *payment = [SKPayment paymentWithProduct:_product];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] addPayment:payment];
}

#pragma mark SKPaymentTransactionObserver

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [self unlockFeature];
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;

                case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                NSLog(@"Transaction Failed");
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:
I'm getting the `productTitle` and `productDescription` in the `NSLog` just fine, but by the time the `PurchaseViewController` loads, the text for them has not been updated yet.  Those methods seem to get called after `viewDidLoad`.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed where the viewDidLoad was.  Silly mistake.

Comment: I have exactly same problem as yours. Can you detail your answer please ?

Comment: Hi @GoldXApp, sorry looks like Stack Overflow closed this question as off topic.